# How to retrieve html source of mobile version website in android?

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I have a application need to get a source of mobile version
Currently I get the source by Jsoup but it still is desktop version.

```
Document doc = null;
     try {
      doc = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   String html = doc.html();

return html;
```

So, how to get the html source of mobile version when the website is reponsive. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting user agent and necessary HTTP headers for Jsoup before requesting the website